# Is it possible to disable the interlocutor's video in BlueJeans Prime for iOS?

Tags: ios, video-conference

I use [BlueJeans Prime](https://www.bluejeans.com/) for videoconference on iOS 11 (iPad). When in a videoconference, is it possible to disable the interlocutor's video?

The motivation is to reduce the network usage.

---

For BlueJeans (not Prime), one can swipe up, which will activate the "low bandwidth" mode:

[image]

Swipe down to go back to the normal mode.

That doesn't work  for BlueJeans Prime.

Comment: Have you tried the developer of the app?  They would be in the best position to answer.

Comment: @Allan thanks yes I reached out to the support and will post their reply as an answer if they reply to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueJeans' tech support told me it is not possible. They don't have any plan to support the option in the future.